# Customize look of selected element

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, indicator

Is there any possibility to customize the look of the active/selected item in the indicator view? Using Data Template Selector or something?
Data template changes every single item.

My goal is to reach this effect:

[image: 2nd item active]

[image: 3rd item active]

Comment: with indicator view you can use visual state, to change the appearance/state when selected and if it still now not work I can help you with one more tweak

Comment: Hi @RonakShethia . Unfortunately  I cant find a name of visual state group which should be proper for indicator view - can you share your idea?

Comment: create a collection view,incase if u have carousal view use same itemsource binding to collection view item source, now in your collection view data template create a frame now here is where the visual state come to the picture check this link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection ,  what would happen when the collecitonview state would be selected change the frame appearance increase the width and corner radius also bind the selectionchange to carousal view selection index

Comment: try this and I am sure you will be able to create what u need, let me know if u still fail to do will try to help u with the code

Answer (score 1):

Try using trigger when color changes of your view at that time increase view's width or you may use view's PropertyChanged event to detect changes in view. I had a similar kind of requirement today and below code worked for me.

```
<IndicatorView
                x:Name="introductionIndicator"
                Grid.Row="2"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                IndicatorColor="{StaticResource PrimaryLightGrayColor}"
                SelectedIndicatorColor="{StaticResource PrimaryYellowColor}">
                <IndicatorView.IndicatorTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <BoxView
                            CornerRadius="10"
                            HeightRequest="6"
                            WidthRequest="20">
                            <BoxView.Triggers>
                                <Trigger TargetType="BoxView" Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryYellowColor}">
                                    <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="30" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </BoxView.Triggers>
                        </BoxView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </IndicatorView.IndicatorTemplate>
            </IndicatorView>
```

result:
[image]